# Custom validator in template driven form always returns null

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to add custom validator in template driven form. I am using Angular 7. Whatever be the value, I am always getting null.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="font-weight:bold">Seats Available</label> <input type="number" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="seats" name="carseat" #carseat="ngModel" validateseat />
  <div *ngIf="carseat.dirty && carseat.errors?.validseat">Required.</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
import { Validator, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[validateseat]"
})
export class Seatvalidatordirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    console.log("dd", control.value);
    return control.value < 0 || control.value > 8 ? { validseat: true } : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: control.value < 0 && control.value > 8  
how is that possiable? ofcorse it will return null all the time.
How can a number be less then 0 and also greater then 8?

Comment: sorry.. it is actually OR ..it is typo error.. after i change it to OR also i am getting null. Just tried with one condition control.value > 8 .That is also giving same result.

Comment: Did you try to debug? Does your validation function gets a valid control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually providing your custom validator, you need to add:

```ts
providers: [
  { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: Seatvalidatordirective, multi: true }
]
```

to your directive:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: "[validateseat]",
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: Seatvalidatordirective, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class Seatvalidatordirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    console.log("dd", control.value);
    return control.value < 0 || control.value > 8 ? { validseat: true } : null;
  }
}
```

Here's a **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mstckk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Glad to hear! :)